# Socialite not reconize

Tags: laravel

i have tried everythings i found online but nothing seems to work.. Here is my problem: I tried to implement authentification with google in laravel using socialite but i have follewed thoses steps describes: [here](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-8-socialite-google-login-example-tutorial/)

here is my composer.json:

```js
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^3.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

here is my file config/app.php:

```js
    'providers' => [
//...
        Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
//...

    ],
```

```js
 'aliases' => [

//..
        'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
      //...

    ],
```

here is my controller, that's where i get my error, on this line "Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect()":

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Socialite;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
    protected $providers = ["google"];
    public function loginRegister(){
        return view ("socialite.login-register");
    }

    public function redirect (Request $rq){
        $provider = $rq->provider;
        if(in_array($provider,$this->providers)){
            return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
        }
    }
}
```

here is a screenshoot of the error:
[image]

laravel doesn't find anywhere the facade socialite even when i tried to import it manually like that =>"Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite" ..
i tried to download again the package and  tried also some cmd like composer dump-autoload.., to try regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project but it' won't work. Thanks in advance for any advices and help.

Comment: For us to help you with your error, please include the error you are getting.

Comment: Is it trying to login with Google+? Because Google+ has been already depracted.

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank i edit my post to include a screenshoot of th error..

Comment: @MátyásGrőger no with google account (gmail)..

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it does not find the package Socialite.
Try to add the use of the package at the beginning of your controller:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
```

Comment: i edited my post..

Comment: try delete all your vendor folder and run composer install. This helped me sometimes with strange vendor issues.

Comment: i tried, it does'nt work..
unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem too, but i resolve with something stupid solution.
first of all you should install package with this command

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

and then you should close your IDE. and then you should open IDE again.
i do always this solution. and finally work it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you set up your google console, most of the errors are done there, I have just solved one issue with multiple checks on it